# How can I know if the partial derivatives exist in this case?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider the function:

f(x,y) =

{ 
abs(x)*y/sqrt(x^2+y^2) when (x,0) != (0,0)

0 when (x,0) = (0,0)
}

How can I know if the partial derivatives exist and how do i find them? In addition, can this function have continuous partial derivatives?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/)

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2287058/discontinuity-and-the-existence-of-partial-derivatives